# Proper way to dispose of map?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have a page where I am dynamically inserting and removing an openlayers3 map from the DOM. However, I found that with prolonged usage (adding and removing map over and over) that memory usage climbs without ever going down. What is the proper way to release the resources being used by the openlayers map?

Currently, I have a function which does the following (but doesn't seem to be releasing the resources):

```
function deleteMap() {
  layer1 = null;
  layer2 = null;
  map.setTarget();
  map = null;
}
```

For those who are wondering layer1 and 2 are setup like the following:

```
var layer1 = new ol.layer.Vector({ ...layerinfo goes here... });
```

Comment: Do you still notice the memory leak with `map.setTarget(null)`? Are you unregistering all event listeners?

Comment: And which version are you using? Recently a bug was fixed related to that (see https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3420). This fix will be included in the next release.